# How to Invoke JS function in IFrame from code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, iframe

Asp.Net 4.5 (WebForm)

How can I invoke a js function in Iframe from code behind successfully?
I am using RegisterClientScriptBlock to fire JS function in **aspx** page that in turn invokes the JS function in **html** page of iframe.

The Client Button in main page works fine.
The Server Button does not work as intended. However it does recognize the iframe object and contentWindow.

**Error**

- TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'TestFunc'

Any constructive help would be appreciated. Note: this is a stripped down example for clarity.

**MainPage.aspx**

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function InvokeJS(param) {
        var iframe = document.getElementById("MyIFrame");
        try {
            iframe.contentWindow.TestFunc(param);

            //=============================================================
            //Would really like to use the .apply method over calling the 
            //function directly. This does work in pure HTML, but not aspx
            //============================================================= 
            //var _ARGS = [];
            //_ARGS.push(param);
            //iframe.contentWindow('TestFunc').apply(null, _ARGS);

        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="ServerButton" runat="server" Text="Server" />
            <input id="ClientButton" type="button" value="Client" onclick="InvokeJS('From Client');" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <iframe id="MyIFrame" runat="server" src="Pages/Test.html" style="width: 700px; height: 300px;"></iframe>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
</body>
```

**MainPage.aspx (CodeBehind)**

```
Protected Sub ServerButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ServerButton.Click
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType, "InvokeJS", "InvokeJS('From Server');", True)
End Sub
```

**Test.html (loads into iframe)**

```
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function TestFunc(param) {
        document.getElementById("DisplayParam").innerHTML = param;
    }
</script>
</head>
   <body>
      <h1>HTML Page</h1>
      <h2 id="DisplayParam"></h2>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: After the button is pressed, what does the view source look like? What happens if you put the ClientScriptBlock directly in the OnLoad, does it execute? Do you have any JS error when debugging in the browser?

Comment: @the_lotus Error has been added to question, I added ClientScriptBlock window.onload = TestFunc; still does not work, and all i could see that changed in view source was the requestId

Answer (score 0):

window.onload = TestFunc(); doesn't work because Test.html actually didn't fully loaded before the onload event raised, it's same with ServerButton, because the scriptblock was registered before the test.html loaded. that's why no TestFunc is not available to call.

You can try

```
<asp:Button ID="ServerButton" runat="server" Text="Server" OnClientClick="InvokeJS('From Server');" />
```

I don't think you like it if you want it to do something before run the script

Then play this trick

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     //this is help check if postback by Server Button, if yes then invoke
     var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
     prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
     function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
         if (args._postBackElement.id == '<%=ServerButton.ClientID%>')
             $('#MyIFrame').load(function(){
                 InvokeJS('From Client');
                 console.log('load the iframe');
             });


        }

 </script>
```